# How to create own types in Nuxt Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

When I use `$_app` in Nuxt, it says `$_app` doesn't exist on `this`. I want to include `$_app` as my own type in Nuxt type. I tried this:

```
import Vue from "vue"

interface AppMixin {
    user: any
}

declare module "vue/types/vue" {
    interface Vue {
        $_app: AppMixin
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's correct. I don't even know where to import this code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to make sure it is working.

Let's say you need to provide `$_app` which has `AppMixin` type:

```
/**
 * Extends interfaces in Vue.js
 */

import Vue from "vue"

interface AppMixin {
   user: string
}

declare module "vue/types/vue" {
  interface Vue {
    $_app: AppMixin
  }
}
```

Then, you need to name this file correctly: `vue.d.ts` and put it in your paths that are included in `include` from `tsconfig.json`.

I usually create `shims/` subfolder in the project's directory, like so: https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-vue-template/tree/master/template/client/shims

And configure it properly, like so: https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-vue-template/blob/master/template/tsconfig.json#L43

If done correctly, your calls to `this.$_app.user` inside your `vue` components will have `string` type revealed.

### Docs

- Declaration files in TypeScript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html
- `Vue` instance extending example: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/types/vue.d.ts